# Installing jupyter-contrib-nbextension on Google Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I wanted to install hinterland for use in google colab. I followed the installation instructions on [official page](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

Basically I did the following steps:

```
!pip install https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tarball/master
!jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

Now when I want to enable any particular extension say 'hinterland' I do the following:

```
!jupyter nbextension enable  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/hinterland/hinterland.js
```

But this gives me an error saying:

```
Enabling notebook extension /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/hinterland/hinterland.js...
  - Validating: problems found:
    - require?  X /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/hinterland/hinterland.js
```

How do I fix this? Am I going wrong in any step?

Or is there any other better way of installing these extensions specifically for google colab.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just run `!jupyter nbextension enable hinterland/hinterland`:
[image]

Comment: Make sure to type:

```!jupyter contrib nbextension install --user```

Comment: I've successfully installed a number of extensions thanks to this and a few other resources, BUT, so far I'm still struggling to actually USE them! For example, the highly useful "nbextension configurator" is installed, but I've no idea where to access it. Ouch.