# codefolding on google colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I've tried enabling code folding on google colab with

```
!jupyter nbextension enable codefolding/main
```

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292456/installing-jupyter-contrib-nbextension-on-google-colab) and using the command line found [here](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

However the response on colab is

```
Enabling notebook extension codefolding/main...
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X codefolding/main
```

Is it possible to do codefolding on colab?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you didn't perform the second step of the installation process after  `!pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`. Install javascript and css files also.

```
!jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

> This step copies the nbextensions' javascript and css files into the jupyter server's search directory, and edits some jupyter config files.

Answer (score -1):

Also (I realize this is more textfolding/outline folding rather than codefolding) but you can fold sections under a markdown header in colab.

Answer (score -1):

I have used simple code folding with the help of text cells and making them a heading. Try out the following steps:
1. Add a text cell and use the following text
2. Then add a code cell and write your code.

```
### Your custom text...
```